# Do frameworks like Vue.js or React.js cause SEO problems?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, react-js, vue-js

Frameworks like Vue.js or React.js hide most things in their source code and only javascript code remains. So H1 tags, img tags, paragraphs, in short, most things related to technical seo do not appear in the source code.

Could this cause an SEO issue? Or can Google read these javascript codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this cause an SEO issue?

Yes. JavaScript can and does cause a lot of issues for SEOs.

> can Google read these javascript codes?

Google can execute JavaScript and render JavaScipt-based websites. But there are a lot of issues.

One option is, to have all relevant content already in the initial HTML and only add functionality with JavaScript. This is called Hydration.

The other option is server-side rendering. Also called pre-rendering. You basically execute the JavaScript and render the website and serve that to Google as HTML. Solutions exist for most JavaScript frameworks, like PreactJS or PreRender.